# How to check user if online from mysql database

Tags: android, mysql

I am creating my first app in android and am using MySQL database. I want to check if the user is online from the database. So far I have gotten this code of checking if the device is connected to internet. Do I need to save this data to the database or am I going in the wrong direction?

```
public boolean isOnline( ) {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi=false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile=false;
  ConnectivityManager cm=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);    
          NetworkInfo activeNetwork=cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(activeNetwork!=null){
                if(activeNetwork.getType()==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                    if(activeNetwork.isConnected())
                      haveConnectedWifi=true;

            }else if(activeNetwork.getType()==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
               {
                if(activeNetwork.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile=true;

            }
        }
        return haveConnectedMobile||haveConnectedWifi;
    }
```

Comment: How does the database used for checking if the user is online? Which user are you talking about? Show example

Comment: User of the android app he can register and login and the data is stored in mysql database so now i want to know if he is online or offline from the database

Comment: I think you have to simply check whether internet connection is available when user tries to register or login or whatever! Let me know if I am correct or not!

Comment: periodically update the time when he was last online, and check if the last update happened earlier that that time - he is offline